# Solve in $C$ : $p(x)=x^4+2x^3-x^2-2x+7=0$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, roots, cubics

Find all root :

$p(x)=x^4+2x^3-x^2-2x+7=0$

Where $p(\alpha)=0$ ,

$\alpha=\sqrt{2}+\omega$

$\omega=e^{\frac{2iπ}{3}}$

My try :

Since : $\alpha$ root of equation then

$\bar\alpha$

also root

But I don't know how I complete to find all root

Answer is :

$x_1=\alpha$

$x_2=\sqrt{2}+\bar\omega$

$x_3=-\sqrt{2}+\bar\omega$

$x_2=-\sqrt{2}+\omega$

Comment: Find $\dfrac{p(x)}{(x-\alpha)(x-\bar\alpha)}=q(x)$

Answer (score 1):

As Shubham Joni has already mentioned in a comment, if you know two roots $\alpha$ and $\bar\alpha$ of this polynomial, you can decompose it in the form
$$ p(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\bar\alpha) q(x)$$
where $q(x)$ is a polynomial of second degree, and its roots can be found through its discriminant. To find $q(x)$ itself you can use [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) method.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the first step in solving an equation of fourth degree is to clear by substitution the term in $x^3$.
In our case, this is done by substituting $x+\frac 12=y$. So $x= y-\frac 12$, we plug in this value and get succesively
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= x^4 + 2x^3-x^2-2x+7\ ,\\
g(y) &:= f(y-\frac 12) \\
&= y^4 -\frac 52 y^2+\frac {121}{16}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we have luck, we get a biquadratic equation, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
y^2 
&= 
\frac 12\left(\frac 52\pm \sqrt{\left(\frac 52\right)^2-4\cdot\frac {121}{16}}\right)
\\
&= 
\frac 12\left(\frac 52\pm 
\sqrt{-24}\right)
=\frac 14(5\pm 4\sqrt{-6})
=\frac 54 \pm \sqrt 6
\\
&=
\left(\frac{\sqrt{-3}}2\pm\sqrt 2\right)^2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the $y$--roots of the polynomial $g$ are
$$
\pm \frac{\sqrt{-3}}2\pm\sqrt 2\ ,
$$
and the $x$--roots of $f$ are:
$$
-\frac 12\pm \frac{\sqrt{-3}}2\pm\sqrt 2\ .
$$

Computer check, [sage](https://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: var('x,y');
sage: f(x) = x^4 + 2*x^3 - x^2 - 2*x + 7
sage: g(y) = f(y-1/2).expand()
sage: g(y)
y^4 - 5/2*y^2 + 121/16

sage: g.roots(multiplicities=False)
[-1/2*sqrt(4*I*sqrt(6) + 5),
 1/2*sqrt(4*I*sqrt(6) + 5),
 -1/2*sqrt(-4*I*sqrt(6) + 5),
 1/2*sqrt(-4*I*sqrt(6) + 5)]

sage: f.roots(multiplicities=False)
[-1/2*I*sqrt(3) - sqrt(2) - 1/2,
 -1/2*I*sqrt(3) + sqrt(2) - 1/2,
 1/2*I*sqrt(3) - sqrt(2) - 1/2,
 1/2*I*sqrt(3) + sqrt(2) - 1/2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir